# Верно ли расставлены знаки препинания? (1)

Tags: пунктуация

**Приближение науки к бизнесу сегодня – если не самая важная, то одна из определяющих вещей.**

Верно ли расставлены знаки препинания?

Comment: Бизнес не стационарен. Лучше не приближать, а сближать науку и бизнес.

Answer (score 1):

В этом предложении акцент на *сегодня* неуместен, а слово "вещь" соответствует заниженному (разговорному) стилю. Я бы написал так, например:

**Сегодня приближение науки к бизнесу – если не самая важная, то одна из определяющих тенденций.**

В такой редакции можно утверждать, что знаки препинания расставлены верно.

Дополнение.

Согласен с замечанием @shampar. Мы наблюдаем взаимное сближение науки и бизнеса, а не одностороннее проближение науки к бизнесу. Но это уточнение выходит за рамки филологии, поэтому оставляю его на усмотрение автора.

Answer (score 0):

Согласна с заменой слова *вещь* словом *тенденция*.  А вот позиция наречия  ***сегодня*** зависит от контекста. (Кстати, в первой части заданного предложения  ударение не падает на ***сегодня***).

**Приближение науки к бИзнесу сегодня – если не самая важная, то одна из определяющих тенденций.**

Тире ставится между группой подлежащего (приближение) и группой сказуемого (одна из тенденций), причем группа сказуемого включает   определения, связанные составным союзом ЕСЛИ НЕ...ТО.

Comment: По-моему, чтобы "услышать" тире, нужно поставить ударение на слово,  предшествующее этому тире. В противном случае получается каша из слов.

Comment: В данном случае группа подлежащего из 4-х слов  "не читается" как единая фраза с ударением на последнем слове, наречие выглядит как детерминант, который приходится выделять голосом, а это уже неудобно. А  в приведенном варианте  ударение предшествует "сегодня", и наречие как бы вписывается в паузу. Смещение ударения (на "к бизнесу") - это и есть логическое выделение, а ударение на последнем слоге фразы - просто фразовое (тоническое) ударение. Вы попробуйте эти варианты чтения предложения.